# Add bottom margin after specific row id

Tags: php, html, css

> *This is my database structure:*
>
> [image]
>
> *This is my current page:*
>
> [image]

**How can i add a bottom margin after row with a specific id?**

In this example, the first 2 rows (*id* `1` and `2`) have a bottom margin `~ 10px` ; while the rest have bottom margin `0px`

[image]

**code:**

```
echo "<div class='calc_container'> 

<input type='hidden' class='id_3' name='id[]' value='".$row['ID']."'>

<input type='text' class='budget_3' name='Budget[]' value='".$row['Budget']."'>

<input type='text' class='avail_region_3' name='Availed_in_Regions[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_Regions']."'>

<input type='text' class='req_kbl_3' name='Requested_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Requested_in_KBL']."'>

<input type='text' class='rec_kbl_3' name='Received_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Received_in_KBL']."'>

<input type='text' class='avail_kbl_3' name='Availed_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_KBL']."'>

<input type='text' class='balance_3' name='Balance[]' value='".$row['Balance']."'>

</div>";}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector by attribute value. Sample:

```
input[value='1'] {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/y29hmjzd/)

Comment: Value is not hard-coded in the question's code. Its coming from database. then how above code will work?

Answer (score 1):

you can code like this-

```
echo "<div class='calc_container'"; if($row['ID']==1) echo " style='margin-bottom:10px;'"; echo "> 

        <input type='hidden' class='id_3' name='id[]' value='".$row['ID']."'>

        <input type='text' class='budget_3' name='Budget[]' value='".$row['Budget']."'>

        <input type='text' class='avail_region_3' name='Availed_in_Regions[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_Regions']."'>

        <input type='text' class='req_kbl_3' name='Requested_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Requested_in_KBL']."'>

        <input type='text' class='rec_kbl_3' name='Received_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Received_in_KBL']."'>

        <input type='text' class='avail_kbl_3' name='Availed_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_KBL']."'>

        <input type='text' class='balance_3' name='Balance[]' value='".$row['Balance']."'>

        </div>";
```

Comment: the structure is wrong because dreamweaver is showng error

Comment: are u using php ?, have u closed parenthesis properly ? comment error ?

Comment: Thanks it worked for id 1 how to add another ids like id 2,5,8.

Comment: change the if condition like -  if(($row['ID']==1) || (($row['ID']==2) || (($row['ID']==3)))  or you can set your query depends. if it solved your problem then mark it right answer , thanks